# How can I merge an array of maps of maps into a single map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Current

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID     |map                                                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|105    |[{bia, {4 -> 1}}, {compton, {5 -> 1}}, {alcatraz, {3 -> 6}}]               |
|106    |[{compton, {4 -> 5}}]                                                      |
|107    |[{compton, {5 -> 99}}]                                                     |
|108    |[{bia, {1 -> 5}}, {compton, {1 -> 1}}]                                     |
|101    |[{alcatraz, {1 -> 2}}]                                                     |
|102    |[{alcatraz, {1 -> 2}}]                                                     |
|103    |[{alcatraz, {1 -> 2}}, {alcatraz, {2 -> 2}}, {alcatraz, {3 -> 2}}]         |
|104    |[{alcatraz, {1 -> 4}}, {alcatraz, {2 -> 2}}, {alcatraz, {3 -> 2}}]         |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Desired

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID     |map                                                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|105    |{bia, {4 -> 1}}, {compton, {5 -> 1}}, {alcatraz, {3 -> 6}}                 |
|106    |{compton, {4 -> 5}}                                                        |
|107    |{compton, {5 -> 99}}                                                       |
|108    |{bia, {1 -> 5}}, {compton, {1 -> 1}}                                       |
|101    |{alcatraz, {1 -> 2}}                                                       |
|102    |{alcatraz, {1 -> 2}}                                                       |
|103    |{alcatraz, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 2}                                        |
|104    |{alcatraz, {1 -> 4, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 2}                                         |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want the final map to be that the first map level is the key for a location (e.g. `alcatraz`, `bia`, `compton`) and the second level is a number representing a group and the ultimate value is a count.

I got the current table by doing something like:

```
.groupBy(col("ID")).agg(collect_list(map($"LOCATION", map($"GROUP", $"COUNT"))) as "map")
```

JSON representation of desired format for more clarity

```
{
    "alcatraz": {
        "1": 100,
        "2": 300
    }, 
    "bia": {
        "2": 767
    },
    "compton": {
        "1": 888,
        "2": 999,
        "3": 1000
    }, 

}
```

I've seen some other stackoverflow posts for merging simple maps but since it's a map of a map those solutions didn't work.

I've been playing with `udf` but haven't had luck.  Is there an easy way to acomplish my goal in scala?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is using this defined udf:

```scala
    val joinMap = udf { values: Seq[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]] => {
      var newMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Map[String, Int]] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Map[String, Int]]()
      for (value <- values) {
        for ((k, v) <- value) {
          for ((sub_k, sub_v) <- v) {
            if (newMap.contains(k)) {
              newMap(k) += (sub_k -> sub_v)
            } else {
              newMap(k) = v
            }
          }
        }
      }
      newMap
    } }
```

You can use this by doing

```scala
.withColumn("map", joinMap(col("map")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) in scope, you can do it this way:

```
def mergeMaps(values: Seq[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]): Map[String, Map[String, Int]] = {
  import cats.implicits._
  values.foldLeft(Map.empty)(_ |+| _)
}
```

(Note: cats offers even more compact syntax for that, but that would make it even less obvious what's happening under the hood.)

But beware: in case two "inner maps" have the same keys, the above would add the integer values, so `Seq(Map("1" -> Map("1" -> 1)), Map("1" -> Map("1" -> 1)))` would be merged to `Map("1" -> Map("1" -> 2))`. If that's a problem and you need the exact same behavior as in your solution, you could modify the solution like this:

```
def mergeMaps(values: Seq[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]): Map[String, Map[String, Int]] = {
  import cats.implicits._
  implicit val takeRightIntSemiGroup = new cats.Semigroup[Int] {
    def combine(x: Int, y: Int): Int = y
  }
  values.foldLeft(Map.empty)(_ |+| _)
}
```